# React SVG rendering issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I'm trying to import and SVG logo as a component and I get the error as seen in the screenshot below.

Opening the SVG into a web browser, this renders fine as expected but when dropping into my app it doesn't like it for some reason.

The only thing I note is the name of the SVG - the actual name of the svg is "test.svg" however, the error recognises it as "test.5d5d9eef.svg". I'm not sure where or how this number is being generated.

Please also note the "SVG" code within my component is a test to see if this will render and it does render just fine.

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';

import MainLogo from '../../../assets/svg/logos/test.svg';

export default class Logo extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="logo-wrap col-xs-2">
                <h1>Heading</h1>
                <MainLogo />
                 <svg>
                    <circle cx={50} cy={50} r={10} fill="red" />
                  </svg>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: An SVG is not automatically a usable component in React, it's a collection of SVG tags. Are you trying to use it in an image? I would recommend putting all your SVG tags in a separate component, then doing what you are.

Comment: @AndrewLi Do you mean importing the svg as "src" on an image tag? I tried that and it rendered. I guess there's no real issue doing it this way? Code: <img src={MainLogo} />

Comment: You need to convert your SVG to a react component.

Comment: @Filth Yeah. If you really want the whole SVG, and not make it part of an img, just create another component will all the markup of the SVG.

Comment: @AndrewLi Ok thanks, yes I'd prefer to render as whole SVG. Do you have an article on how to create a component with markup as SVG like you are suggesting please?

Comment: @Filth Just take your SVG markup, without any of the XML such as `xml:ns` then paste it into a React component.

Comment: @AndrewLi Wow I'm amazed this works! How would you organise your folder structure based on this? Would be a bit odd to go into an assets folder to svgs and find an logo.js file no?

Comment: @Filth Yeah, I had this dilemma too. Just make it a component and place it in the components folder

Comment: @AndrewLi I could be making a school boy error here but I set up an SVG folder with the file "logo.js" and just pasted the svg code in there... My app complains because React is not defined - that makes sense? How'd you get around this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a generic component which accepts some props and creates any SVG for you, like this:

```
import React from 'react';

export class BuildNewSVG extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
render() {    
  let bg = props.color || '#000';
  let height = props.height || props.size || '24';
  let width = props.width || props.size || '24';
  let path1 = props.path1 || 'M7 10l5 5 5-5z';
  let path2 = props.path2;
  let fill1 = props.fill1 || '';
  let fill2 = props.fill2 || 'none';
  let viewBox = props.viewBox || '0 0 24 24';

  return (
    <svg fill={bg} className={props.class} height={height} viewBox={viewBox} width={width}>
      <path d={path1} fill={fill1} />
      <path d={path2} fill={fill2} />
    </svg>
  );
}
}
```

You can call the component like this:

```
<BuildNewSVG color={'red'} height={'100'} viewBox={'0 0 24 24'} width={'100'} size={'50'}
        path1="M10 20v-6h4v6h5v-8h3L12 3 2 12h3v8z" path2="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill1={'#ffffff'} fill2={'red'} />
```

Note: This will be a generic component and will only accept SVG paths (path1 and path2). Path2 is the outer container. Any simple or complex shape (for example: circle) can be defined as svg path(s).

Comment: Very elegant solution, I will try this.